# Radioactive decay with Curies

Tags: radiation, radioactivity, half-life

I want to make sure I am approaching this problem correctly:

Element X has a half-life of 100 years. If I have a 128 Curie sample of element X, how long will I have to wait until its radioactivity has decreased to 0.5 Curies?

I believe I can use the radioactive decay law? Where N(T) = .5 Curies, inital is 128 Curies... etc. I am not sure and the unit of Curies is confusing to me. 
$$N(T) = N_{0} \cdot e^{-\frac{ln2}{half-life}t}$$

Comment: If you have a $128\,\mathrm{Ci}$ sample of *anything* you'd better know a lot about radiation protection ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Curie is a less used measure of activity of a radioactive substance $($Personally I'm a lot more familiar with the Bequerel$)$. So, in short, yes you can use that equation to calculate the final activity.

Looking at the units you can see that in the power of $e$ part you essentially have $\frac{t}{t}$ which cancels out, leaving you with just $Ci=Ci$, so it checks out :p.

Comment: What do you mean it cancels out?

Comment: In the same way that in 9/9 the top it 'cancels out' to 1, the units of time in t/t 'cancel out' to 1, as in they disappear.

Comment: *"I'm sure we're all more familiar with the Bequerel"* Really depends on your age.  That thing wasn't established as an SI unit until after I was born and hadn't come to dominate in the textbooks until I was already in grad school.

Comment: @dmckee Apologies - Being younger I didn't think about that - lemme edit it :)

Comment: No need to apologize. Most of SI has been around for a long time, so the few cases where something is "recent" cause unexpected generation gaps. I almost always write in Bequerels, but I sometimes still think in Curies (or mostly in microCuiries).

Comment: @dmckee Okay - I understand that now :) Looking on wikipedia the Curie does seem to be rather large compared to the good 'ol Bq

Comment: @CooperCape okay thanks! I got t = 800 years, is that correct?

Comment: @user7252850 Yes, that is what I get as well :)

Comment: Darned shame, really.  Henri Bequerel earned his share of the Nobel Prize mostly by not throwing away the photographic plate that got spoiled when he left it in the same drawer with his mineral specimens.  Marie Curie and her husband worked their ***es off for months to earn their share of it.